# implementing multi user types for hospital management system

Tags: python, django, django-models

so I am building a hospital management system as my pet project in Django, and one thing that I realized is that you need implement a 3 user multi system which includes the HR, staff(doctor) and patient. Been surfing through the internet for the best implementation and came up short. The best I saw was this tutorial blog on [How to implement multi user system](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html#practical-example), but it doesn't cover on using more than 3 user like I want to. This is my current user/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


    USER_CHOICE = [
        ('D', 'Doctor'),
        ('P', 'Patient'),
        ('R', 'Receptionist'),
        ('HR', 'HR')
    ]
    # Create your models here.
    class User(AbstractUser):
        """
        user class for different users in the database
        """
        user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_CHOICE, max_length=3, default=None)

    def is_doctor(self):
        """ return True if the user is a doctor and False if not """
        if self.user_type == 'D':
            return True
        return False

    def is_patient(self):
        """ return True if the user is a patient and False if not """
        if self.user_type == 'P':
            return True
        return False

    def is_receptionist(self):
        """ return True if the user is a receptionist and False if not """
        if self.user_type == 'R':
            return True
        return False

    def is_hr(self):
        """ return True if the user is HR and False if not """
        if self.user_type == 'HR':
            return True
        return False

    class Meta:
        """ Descending order for id """
        # ordering = ('id',)
```

I need help on the best way to implement this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use `flags` in `User model`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_hr = models.BooleanField()
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField()
    is_patient = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: i understand what you did here but how do I manage the authentication system with it

Comment: In the link you sent I noticed that flags are discussed.

Comment: yes, they are but, suitable for =<2 users. So that is y am kindly concerned with it or I can do it as you said